# Is there any specific total count/detail/list of Wesley Crusher's womanizing?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

From [a now-deleted page on TVTropes](https://web.archive.org/web/20120210082922/https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AManIsNotAVirgin) (Internet archive backup).

> Ironically enough, the record holder for most tail in TNG might actually be Wesley Crusher.

I haven't watched the whole of *TNG*, but at the beginning of the series, it looked like Wesley was presented as a typical non-dating nerd, so the above-quoted note seems strange.

**Is there some reference with a total # or better yet a detailed list of romantic liaisons of Wesley Crusher on *TNG*?**

Comment: His name links to the "CreatorsPet" page, so I have the feeling it's just wishful thinking

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *This list is incomplete; you can help [by expanding it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/7231/edit).*

## In the foreground

#### Season 2

210 - "The Dauphin"

[image: In this frame from "The Dauphin," Salia, left in a brown dress, facing right, and Wesley, to her left in a Starfleet tunic, are observing something off-screen to the right against a night-time planetary backdrop with rugged hills and star-lit sky.]

#### Season 5

506 - "The Game"

[image: Wesley, leaning forward, left, stands behind Ensign Lefler, seated in a frame from "The Game."]

## Possible background romances

### Season 1

107 - "Justice"

[image: "Edo girl" (left in a revealing pink dress, facing right, hands on Wesley's arms) greets Wesley (right, facing left, arms at sides in a long-sleeved brown tunic) in the episode "Justice" with two Edo boys (in pink shorts) in the background]

### Season 3

301 - "Evolution"

[image: Wesley, in his Starfleet uniform, stands with his arm around an uncredited young woman in yellow and blue in this shot from the end of "Evolution." The scene takes place in 10-Forward, and they stand at a table crowded with other young people.]

Comment: Damnit, I just lost...

Comment: Not sure if Wesley slept with Ashley Judd's character, but I'm pretty sure he never had sex with the Dauphin. The most they ever did was kiss. And since the trope is about not being a virgin, simply "hooking up" doesn't really count.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté the asker wants "**a detailed list of [the] romantic liasons of Wesley Crusher**"

Comment: I would assume that he wants a list pertaining to the quoted statement (that Wesley is "the record holder for most tail in TNG"). I mean, the current list still disproves that, but I just think the list ought to remain true to the assertion being analyzed here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we could get @wilw over here to discuss this with us, if enough of us asked. Surely he remembers hooking up with Ashley Judd.

Comment: Pretty sure it was "Evolution" - scene at the end of episode in Ten Forward, Crusher spots Wesley entering with an unnamed girl. One has to imagine if anything "interesting" went on between them off-screen. Also, "Justice" - all that apparent hedonism going on, although Wesley may have been under-age.

Answer (score 9):

I went through the [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/) links, as well as [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.org), [Internet Movie Database](https://www.imdb.com), and the [Wikipedia *Star Trek: The Next Generation* Episode List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_episodes) to check episode summaries.  If there was any doubt, I pulled out my *ST:TNG* DVDs and skipped through the episodes for reminders of the storyline, just in case there might have been a Wesley B-Plot (or even C-Plot) that I may have forgotten.

I found nothing on TVTropes to support their claim of Wesley holding the record for romantic liaisons on Next Generation.  I did find the following:

*The Dauphin*: Wesley becomes romantically involved with Salia, the titular character.  There's no indication he had sex with her, but it was clearly romantic.

*The Game*: He bonds with Ensign Robin Lefler.  There's no indication the relationship continues after Wesley leaves the *Enterprise* at the end of the episode.  It's not clear if they ever slept together and it could be argued there was a friendship and not a romance.

*The First Duty*: I don't think there was a romance going on between Wesley and either of his female crewmates in Nova Squadron.  It's possible, since there are times it seems like there might be more, but that is likely just the closeness team or crewmates in such a situation would develop normally.

Other than that, I could not find indications that Wesley was in other romantic relationships.

Comment: Now, for the "Ironically enough" bit - can you name another character with a record comparable to even this?

Comment: @Random832, Riker had more dates than this.  So did Picard.  The latter is arguable, but the former is not.

Comment: If we're talking the entire ST universe and not just TNG, then Kirk definitely had more dates than this.

Comment: @Flimzy: not *that* many more, though: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32051/how-many-alien-women-has-capt-admiral-kirk-slept-with

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: You don't think 8-9 confirmed plus 7-6 possible (not to mention Kirk's alien 3-some in the new movie) > Wesley's 3 possible?  Your math and mine are quite different...

Comment: @Flimzy: sure it's > but not >>

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: I'm not sure what distinction you're trying to make, but it's *at least* a magnitude of 2.6 greater, and possibly a magnitude of 8.5 greater. Any way you slice it, it's ahelluvalotmore.

Answer (score 3):

I just watched the game episode. Towards the end, Ensign Lefler is watching Wesley pack to leave to go back to the academy. Right before they leave the quarters she gives him a gift, but it appears that she simply picked it up off a table in the room. This would imply that they were in Ensign Lefler's quarters, so it would seem that Wesley's belongings were in her quarters. Also, looking around the room a bit it doesn't seem like they're in Dr Crusher's room but there is a slight feminine feel to the room. So it's my opinion that Wesley hit that at least once and was sleeping in her room while he was on board after the game incident was over.

Comment: That, or she brought it with her when she came to his room and set it on the table rather than holding it the whole time.

Comment: The transcript on Chakoteya says it's Wesley's room. On the other hand, the scene starts with her holding what looks like his undergarments and says she never saw him "wear these", which implies at least some stage of undress in the past. It should also be noted that the quarters are the larger quarters set (with windows), which are usually reserved for higher-ranking crew (Picard, Riker, Troi, Dr. Crusher) and guests.