# How many alien women has Capt/Admiral Kirk slept with?

Tags: star-trek, sexuality

It's an ongoing punchline that Kirk has slept with many women across the galaxy.

Is it actually based in fact though? In the TV series and movies, how many actual women did Kirk boldly go into with his Enterprise? (pun intended). Please distinguish aliens from humans, for those who are curious, and also indicate which are from the TV series and which are from movies.

The only woman I know for sure he [Zap Brannigen](https://futurama.fandom.com/wiki/Zapp_Brannigan)'d was the lady who had his son.

Comment: http://www.martialdevelopment.com/wordpress/wp-content/images/captain-kirk-vs-gorn.jpg

Comment: You mean the woman who had his child in the movies? Don't forget he also got a Native American woman pregnant on the television series, though he also got her stoned to death before she had the baby.

Comment: There were a lot of scenes of Kirk *kissing* females in TOS (including at one point Uhura). That's a far cry from actual sexual intercourse, but its also as close as you could represent on network TV in the 1960's. You perhaps ought to lay out how to count such things.

Comment: Also, is actual sleep a requirement?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

***Q: How many ALIEN females did Kirk have sex with?***

First of all, to answer the original question, we will limit to aliens-only (full list based on data in the second part of the answer):

**A: Total of 4 to 7 including the Universe reboot, depending on your inclusiveness (out of 11-17 total women)**.

- Of past dalliances, 0 of 5 were alien
- Of known non-canon book ones, 0 of 2 were alien
- Of movie ones, 0 of 1 were alien
- Of TV show ones, 2 to 4 out of 4 confirmed ones were alien:

  - Drusilla ["Bread and Circuses"]
  - Deela ["Wink of an Eye"]
  - Elaan ["Elaan of Troyius"] - MAYBE - *not 100% confirmed as sexual partner but very likely.*
  - Miramanee ["The Paradise Syndrome"] - MAYBE - *Strictly speaking, Miramanee is not an alien - she was an Amerind, who were a **human** off-shoot living on an alien planet.*
- Also, 1 of 3 "possibles" from TV show - Odona - was alien ["The Mark of Gideon"].
- In ["Into Darkness"] Kirk is seen in bed with two alien women.

---

***Q: How many total females did Kirk have sex with?***

***SUMMARY:***

| Source | Timeframe | Confirmed | Possible |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TOS TV | Present | 4 (maybe 3) | 3 or 4 |
| TOS TV | Past | 4 | 1 |
| Movies | Past | 0 | 1 |
| Books | All | 1 | 1 |
| Reboot | Present | 2 | 0 |
| **Total** | * | **9-11** | **7-6** |

Please note that non-canon (book) numbers are quite possibly low-balled; as I was going from a fairly small list.

---

***DETAILS***

Someone called "Captain Robert April" did this analysis for TV series, reposted [here](https://www.trekbbs.com/showpost.php?s=236a12818fb9c7272be495c2cfd21243&p=3972735&postcount=56) (they actually went through *every single episode*):

Summary was:

> **So, out of 79 episodes, we have only seven possible instances, and only four of those can we count as confirmed**.

Please note that he also mentioned several instances of PAST dalliances that aren't counted in his summary. **Those were 4 or 5:**

- Carol Marcus.
- Areel Shaw
- Ruth (no last name, played by Shirley Bonne)
- Dr. Janet Wallace
- Janice Lester (maybe)

**Plus 1 possibles from the movie non-TV-series info (non canon books):**

- Antonia from *ST: Generations* - maybe.

**Plus at least 1 confirmed and 1 possible that are known from non canon books:**

- Admiral Lori Ciana (I think this was non-canon book though, not in his list).
- Gillian Taylor (hinted at in a graphic novel)

  However, there probably were more in the books that I don't know of.

---

***Specific examples listed in that post:***

**S1:**

- "Where No Man Has Gone Before" Within the story itself, nope. Brief reference to a "little blonde lab technician" way back at the Academy, later assumed to be Carol Marcus.
- "Court-Martial" Within the story itself, nope, except for that final kiss on the bridge. Areel Shaw had a relationship with Kirk "four years, seven months, and an odd number of days" ago, so this reference doesn't really count.
- "Shore Leave" Another one from the past, Ruth, apparently from back in his Academy days or thereabouts. Doesn't seem that much really happened within the story itself, unless you count her showing up again at the end (17 episodes in and we finally might actually have Kirk getting lucky? Not a good average for an alleged womanizer....)
- "The City on the Edge of Forever" Ah, yes, Edith Keeler. This was true love, kids. However, to set history straight, she had to die. Thus, the crux of the story. Whether or not Kirk got lucky is dependent on how easy you think Edith was (remember, she was an idealistic social worker, so how likely is it that she'd hop into bed with this handsome stranger?), so it's debatable how far this relationship actually went.
- ... "*That's 28 episodes so far, and by my count, Kirk got lucky, during the course of the series to this point, maybe twice. Second season, folks?*"

**S2:**

- "The Deadly Years" Another one from the past (Janet, "six years, four months, and an odd number of days" ago), with no action within the episode itself. Nope.
- "Bread And Circuses" Okay, we've got that slave girl, Drusilla. We now have our, maybe, third time in 43 episodes.
- ... *"So far, two seasons, 55 episodes, possibly three times, and only one of those can we point to with any degree of certainty ("Bread And Circuses")"*.

**S3:**

- "Elaan of Troyius" Maybe. He was in her quarters a loooong time. We'll count this one as confirmed just for argument's sake (that makes two out of a possible four so far)
- "The Paradise Syndrome" Well, Miramanee was pregnant, so that pretty much ends that discussion. Up to five, with only three confirmed.
- "Wink of an Eye" Now this one is another confirmed instance (We see Kirk sitting on the bed, putting his boots back on, while Deela is busy brushing her hair; it's still a mystery how this one slipped by the censors). We are now up to six possible, with four confirmed.
- "The Mark of Gideon" Yeah, I'll give ya this one, although I'm not willing to call this one confirmed. Kirk and Odonna certainly weren't leaving the bridge arm-in-arm to go check the antimatter flow regulators. That makes seven possible, four confirmed.
- "Requiem For Methuselah" Hmm. I don't think this one ever progressed to the physical stage, if only because Kirk was too busy with the Enterprise crew being sick, so this gets a close, but not close enough.
- "Turnabout Intruder" Maybe way back when Kirk and Janice Lester were dating, but within the story, nope.

Comment: I don't think Carol Marcus counts as sleeping with an alien.

Comment: +1 for a very well put together answer!  Also and maybe it's just my memory coloring things but did he ever have anything with Yeoman Rand?

Comment: @Monty129 - He had feelings for her, but they never led to anything that can be suspected as physical intimacy.

Comment: @DVK Except in the Mirror Universe where she was the official "Captain's Woman"...

Comment: What about the green-skinned lady who roomed with Uhura at the academy in the reboot movie?

Comment: @Jeff - Is that a question for Flimzy?

Comment: @DVK: And you, since the edits are to your answer.  I'd say she needs to be counted if *Into Darkness* is.

Comment: @Jeff - since I haven't seen it yet, I will rely on you to edit the data in, as I won't go hunting for proof to try and avoid too many spoilers :)

Comment: +1 because questions and answers like this are why I use stackexchange.

Comment: What about Shahna from Gamesters of Triskelion?

Answer (score 5):

Found this a few years ago.  I agree with this analysis.

> Did Kirk "Sleep Around"? Here's The Absolute TRUTH!  By Jay
>   (PhineasBg@aol.com)
>
> Does Kirk actually have sex with every girl that crosses his path?
>   Well, here's the absolute TRUTH! From "The Cage" to "Star Trek:
>   Generations", I will count every single time Kirk kisses or has sex
>   with a girl for the sole purpose of sexuality. I will also point out
>   times references to Kirk's past loves are implied, and times he uses
>   his charm to gain a tactical advantage. Here's something that will
>   make people that believe this myth cringe: FACTS! The totals will be
>   at the end of the page.
>
> The Original Series
>
> The Cage:  Kirk's not here. This is a story about Captain Pike. 
>   KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Where No Man Has Gone Before:  Kirk doesn't make any sexual moves 
>   toward Dr. Dehner. But a Past girl is mentioned, some fans feel  this
>   is Carol Marcus in Wrath Of Khan.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:1 CHARM:0
>
> The Corbomite Maneuver:  Kirk doesn't make any sexual moves toward
>   anyone.  No female guest stars.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Mudd's Women:  Kirk seems to like Eve, but turns her down.  KISSES:0
>   SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Enemy Within:  Kirk is split between his Good Self and his Evil
>   Self.  The Evil Kirk tries to attack Janice Rand.  Sorry, this is not
>   *Kirk* Kirk.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Man Trap:  The female guest star is (supposedly) an old 
>   girlfriend of McCoy's.  Kirk makes no moves toward her whatsoever. 
>   KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Naked Time:  Even with Kirk under the intoxicating influence  of
>   the virus, he makes no moves toward anyone.  Though he's sad he hasn't
>   time to be with a girl.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Charlie X:  Kirk makes no moves toward Rand  or any female guest
>   stars.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Balance of Terror:  Kirk holds Rand briefly. But she holds him first. 
>   KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> What Are Little Girls Made Of?:  Kirk tells an android to kiss him. 
>   He does this to try to get her to confuse her  programming and to get
>   her to let him go.  There is no sexual interest there whatsoever.  But
>   I will count it as Charm.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:1
>
> Dagger of the Mind:  Helen Noel is an old flame of Kirk's that seems 
>   to want to have some fun again.  But Kirk doesn't do a thing.  He does
>   try to embrace her, but that was a result of  hypnotism. But I will
>   count it as Past.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:1 CHARM:0
>
> Miri:  Kirk is chivalrous  towards Miri. But no sexual attraction  (on
>   his part) whatsoever.  Rand flirts with him briefly, but Kirk ignores
>   it.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Conscience of the King:  Kirk DOES kiss Lenore Karidian.  She and
>   he do seem attracted to one another.  So, for the first time, there is
>   some sexuality that  Kirk at least partially instigates.  But no sex
>   or sexism.  KISSES:1 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Galileo Seven:  This is mostly about Spock.  Kirk flirts with no
>   one.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Court Martial:  Areel Shaw, Kirk's old girlfriend, is there.  They
>   kiss at the end, but Shaw asked  Kirk if she could.  But it does refer
>   to Kirk's Past.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:1 CHARM:0
>
> The Menagerie:  This is another Spock story.  Kirk makes no moves on
>   anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Shore Leave:  Kirk sees a replica of his old girlfriend, Ruth.  This
>   is just a memory, but I'll count it as Past.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:1
>   CHARM:0
>
> The Squire of Gothos:  Kirk has to deal with Trelane throughout this
>   story.  Kirk makes no moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Arena:  Kirk is too busy teaching a Gorn a lesson.  Kirk makes no
>   moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Alternative Factor:  The universe is going to become non-existent.
>   No women. Kirk makes no moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0
>   CHARM:0
>
> Tomorrow is Yesterday:  Kirk has to deal with time paradoxes and
>   Captain Christopher.  Kirk makes no moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0
>   PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Return of the Archons:  Kirk is kissed by surprise, but he doesn't
>   kiss back.  This would've been the perfect opportunity for him to have
>   sex.  But guess what? Kirk makes no moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0
>   PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> A Taste of Armageddon:  There is a nice comraderie between Kirk and
>   Mea,  but nothing overtly sexual.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Space Seed:  Khan gets the girl in this one.  Though she helps Kirk,
>   he makes no moves toward her.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> This Side of Paradise:  This is another Spock story.  Kirk makes no
>   moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Devil in the Dark:  No women to speak of.  Kirk makes no moves on
>   anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Errand of Mercy:  No women to speak of.  Kirk makes no moves on
>   anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The City on the Edge of Forever:  Kirk does say "I'm in love with
>   Edith Keeler,"  But Kirk doesn't kiss, charm, or have sex with her.
>   Again, sorry.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Operation: Annihilate!:  Too busy dealing with Denebian parasites. 
>   Kirk makes no moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Okay, that's Season One.  Kirk's kissed one girl.  Kirk's had no sex. 
>   Four past relationships have been mentioned.  Kirk's used his charm
>   one time.
>
> Now, onto Season Two:
>
> Catspaw:  Kirk charms Sylvia to try to save his crew.  KISSES:0 SEX:0
>   PAST:0 CHARM:1
>
> Metamorphosis:  Kirk makes no moves toward Hedford.  KISSES:0 SEX:0
>   PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Friday's Child:  Eleen is pregnant!  Kirk naturally makes no moves. 
>   KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Who Mourns for Adonais?:  Kirk makes no moves.  Palamas is attracted
>   to Apollo.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Amok Time:  The only sexuality in this story centers around Spock. 
>   Kirk makes no moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Doomsday Machine:  No women to speak of.  Kirk makes no moves on
>   anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Wolf in the Fold:  Kirk is too busy exonerating Scotty of murder. 
>   They watch a dancer early in the episode, but that's it.  KISSES:0
>   SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Changeling:  No women to speak of.  Kirk makes no moves on anyone.
>   KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Apple:  Kirk encourages sexuality on a planet.  But he doesn't
>   have any.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Mirror, Mirror:  Marlena and Kirk flirt, but Kirk was having to
>   pretend  to be the Mirror Universe Kirk.  All Kirk and the other
>   Marlena did was  grin at one another at the end. But I'll count it as
>   Charm.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:1
>
> The Deadly Years:  An old friend of Kirk's, Dr. Janet Wallace,  speaks
>   of old times, so I'll count it as Past.  But there is nothing else. 
>   KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:1 CHARM:0
>
> I, Mudd:  Kirk doesn't even flirt with the very-attractive androids. 
>   KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Trouble With Tribbles:  No women to speak of.  Kirk makes no moves
>   on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Bread and Circuses:  There is definitely some off-screen sex implied
>   here.  For the first time in 43 episodes, it seems, Kirk actually has
>   some sex.  KISSES:0 SEX:1 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Journey to Babel:  Kirk makes no moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0
>   PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> A Private Little War:  Kirk does embrace Nona passionately.  But he
>   was clearly drugged by her.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Gamesters of Triskelion:  Kirk kisses Shahna. Although he seems to
>   be doing it only to  give her some comfort, I'm going to allow it. 
>   Later, Kirk uses his charm to distract Shahna  so he can knock her out
>   and steal her keys.  KISSES:1 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:1
>
> Obsession:  Kirk makes no moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0
>   CHARM:0
>
> The Immunity Syndrome:  Kirk makes no moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0
>   PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> A Piece of the Action:  Kirk ignores flirtations by a gangster's
>   girlfriend.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> By Any Other Name:  Kirk is romantic with Kelinda.  But he does this
>   to make Rojan jealous to save the Enterprise.  Therefore, it only
>   counts as Charm.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:1
>
> Return to Tomorrow:  Kirk was in a ball most of the time.  Sargon was
>   controlling the Captain's body.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Patterns of Force:  Kirk makes no moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0
>   PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Ultimate Computer:  Kirk makes no moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0
>   PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Omega Glory:  Kirk makes no moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0
>   PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Assignment: Earth:  Kirk doesn't flirt with Roberta or Isis.  KISSES:0
>   SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Okay, that's Season Two.  In this season:  Kirk's kissed one girl. 
>   Kirk has sex one time.  One past relationship is mentioned.  Kirk uses
>   his charm four times.
>
> Now, onto Season Three:
>
> Spectre of the Gun:  Chekov gets romantic, but not Kirk.  KISSES:0
>   SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Elaan of Troyius:  Kirk is drugged by Elaan's tears.  Heck, Kirk even
>   resists the effects of the tears.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Paradise Syndrome:  Sorry, Kirk had amnesia and wasn't thinking
>   straight.  He also married her, which is far from being sexist. 
>   KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Enterprise Incident:  The Romulan Commander is far more 
>   interested in Spock.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> And the Children Shall Lead:  Kirk makes no moves on anyone.  KISSES:0
>   SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Spock's Brain:  Lots of girls, and Kirk flirts with none of them. 
>   KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Is There In Truth No Beauty?:  Kirk flirts with Dr. Miranda Jones, 
>   but only to distract her while Spock deals with the  Medusan.
>   Therefore, it only counts as Charm.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:1
>
> The Empath:  Kirk makes no moves toward Gem.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0
>   CHARM:0
>
> The Tholian Web:  Kirk can't even speak in this episode, much less
>   flirt.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> For the World Is Hollow and I Have Touched the Sky:  Kirk makes no
>   moves towards Natira.  She is McCoy's love in this episode.  KISSES:0
>   SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Day of the Dove:  Kirk makes no moves towards Mara or anyone else. 
>   KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Plato's Stepchildren:  Kirk makes the historic interracial kiss with
>   Uhura.  But he was under Parmen's telekinetic control.  KISSES:0 SEX:0
>   PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Wink of an Eye:  Kirk definitely has sex in this episode.  Though it
>   should be noted he only did it to distract the female villain  and to
>   stall for time. For, it is very clear in this episode that Kirk would
>   not  have touched her at all if it wasn't necessary. I will count it
>   as sex, and charm.  KISSES:0 SEX:1 PAST:0 CHARM:1
>
> That Which Survives:  Kirk makes no moves towards  Losira (for obvious
>   reasons).  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Let That Be Your Last Battlefield:  Kirk makes no moves on anyone. 
>   KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Whom Gods Destroy:  Marta throws herself at Kirk and kisses him.  But
>   Kirk is weak and all he wants to do is get out of the asylum. 
>   KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Mark of Gideon:  Whatever happens with Kirk is this episode can be
>   blamed on the schemes of the Gideons.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Lights of Zetar:  Kirk makes no moves toward Mira.  She is
>   Scotty's love interest.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Cloud Minders:  Kirk makes no flirtations towards Vanna or
>   Droxine.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Way to Eden:  Kirk flirts with none of the space hippies. 
>   KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Requiem for Methuselah:  Kirk falls in love with Rayna (almost
>   instantly) and he also kisses her.  This is the one and only episode
>   where Kirk *officially* chases after a girl,  and is most probably
>   where he got his false reputation for being a lady chaser.  (It's kind
>   of ironic, though, that she turns out to be an android at the end). 
>   KISSES:1 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> The Savage Curtain:  Kirk makes no moves on anyone.  KISSES:0 SEX:0
>   PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> All Our Yesterdays:  Zarabeth is Spock's love interest, not Kirk's. 
>   KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:0 CHARM:0
>
> Turnabout Intruder:  Lester is a nut in this episode and  Kirk has no
>   interest in her now. But she was a Past flame.  KISSES:0 SEX:0 PAST:1
>   CHARM:0
>
> And that's Season Three.  In this season:  Kirk's kissed one girl. 
>   Kirk's had sex with one girl.  One past relationship has been
>   mentioned.  Kirk's used his charm two times.
>
> All right. For the entire 79 episode Original Series run:  Kirk's
>   kissed three girls.  Kirk's had sex twice.  Six past relationships
>   have been mentioned.  Kirk's used his charm seven times.

Comment: Where did you find this? Could you [edit] that in?