# How many females has Captain Kirk slept with?

Tags: star-trek, sexuality

To complement this question: [How many alien women has Capt/Admiral Kirk slept with?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32051/how-many-alien-women-has-capt-admiral-kirk-slept-with)

How many TOTAL (alien or not) women has James T. Kirk been sexually involved with? (only going all the way counts, not flirting/being attracted to)

Comment: I have initially mis-read the "alien" question and produced the (IMHO good) "all" Answer. As I didn't want the answer to be wasted, I asked a "all" version of the question to be able to re-use the answer.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32051/how-many-alien-women-has-capt-admiral-kirk-slept-with

Comment: [Meta Discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/are-multiple-variations-of-a-question-with-subtle-distinctions-duplicate)

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: this answer was merged into this answer: [How many alien women has Capt/Admiral Kirk slept with?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32051/how-many-alien-women-has-capt-admiral-kirk-slept-with/32052#32052)