# Who was more of a Casanova , Kirk or Riker (based on count of bedmates)?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos, sexuality, captain-kirk

"Common knowledge" is that on Star Trek, James T. Kirk and William T. Riker are both the Casanovas of their corresponding series.

We know that in Kirk's case, the reputation is somewhat undeserved (as noted in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32051/how-many-alien-women-has-capt-admiral-kirk-slept-with), he bedded between 7 and 11 people, depending on how much of in-universe hard evidence you require; in 79 episodes, 9 movies and many books. <strike>Fanfics excluded</strike>.).

How does Commander Riker compare numerically? Is he more or less of a pick-up artist than Kirk, **based on counting his sexual partners**?

**I'm fine with an answer either simply counting his total bedmates to compare to Kirk, or normalizing the number of sex partners per episode to account for TNG's much longer run.**

Comment: To pre-empt questions about whether "Outcast" counts, the gender of the partner doesn't matter.

Comment: Normally, Riker doesn't get down with dudes, but that night was a special exception.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - Yes, normally neither does [James Bond](http://www.digitalspy.com/movies/news/a437356/daniel-craig-says-james-bond-skyfall-villain-silva-are-not-gay.html)

Comment: Since you're willing to just go on the number of bedmates, I'd suggest focusing the question and title on that to avoid "opinion" closure.

Comment: @phantom42 - isn't that EXACTLY what I did in the last paragraph? I bolded the text asking for **counts**

Comment: I voted to re-open based on that.

Comment: Wasn't there already a question like this one? Could swear there was.

Comment: @Xantec - for Kirk (linked from this question). Not for Riker as far as I can tell

Comment: I can't vote to reopen on this. I hope I'm not being a jackass. It's an interesting question, and worded in such a way that it's not inappropriate (PG-13 at the highest)... but if you put it down to just counting "bedmates", it's no longer worth answering. The interesting part of the question is too subjective, and fixing this makes it a bad one. Sorry DVK.

Comment: @JohnO Deciding whether it "worth answering" was not your job as a voter. Your job as a voter is to enforce the rules, not make question value judgements: that's what votes are for. Your job was to decide whether it was "opinion-based" or whether there were other rules broken meaning it needed to be closed. Furthermore, the equivalent question asked of Kirk has a net 20 upvotes, meaning the users believe the question is of sufficient quality. So even if was your job, you did it poorly.

Comment: The following section was present in the original from the beginning: `I'm fine with an answer either simply counting his total bedmates to compare to Kirk, or normalizing the number of sex partners per episode to account for TNG's much longer run.` It thus was never opinion based. It always asked for numbers, which are not opinions. The same numbers have been asked for Kirk, and that question was not closed and has a net 20 upvotes as of this comment. This never should have been closed. I even reported this question as it appears that section was ignored by multiple voters.

Comment: @trkly Sorry, but my job is not to "enforce the rules". I'm a spirit of the law sort of person anyway. Nor am I bound to allow a dumb/bad question simply because there have been other dumb/bad questions in the past that were not closed. I don't even remember this, but I trust my judgement from a year ago.

Answer (score 14):

Riker is shown to both sleep with more women, sleep with more women as a result of the amount of time covered in the respective *TOS* and *TNG* eras, but less per episode of the series. Riker also treats his sexual partners more like objects, as seen in his treatment of [Ro Laren](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ro_Laren) and [Deanna Troi](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Deanna_Troi) in [*Conundrum*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Conundrum_%28episode%29), as opposed to Kirk's nasty habit of falling in love with and/ or knocking them up. So it somewhat depends on what you consider a "pick-up artist" to be; sheer numbers, numbers over a certain time-span, or the treatment of women you sleep with.

If you scroll down to the "Romance" section of [Riker's *Memory Alpha* page](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/William_T._Riker), you can see that Riker slept with a maximum of 14 'women' that we know of - obviously he and Kirk could have been hosting orgies off-screen in-between episodes for all we know - during the course of *TNG* and the films. If we accept Riker's highest number of 14 and Kirk's highest possible number of 11, we are left with Riker sleeping with 14 people between 2364 and 2379, just shy of 1 woman a year, whereas Kirk slept with 11 women in the period pre-2265, when *TOS* began, 2293, when *The Undiscovered Country* occurred. That's 11:35 as compared to Riker's 14:15. On the other hand, if we assume for the purposes of this question that Riker and Kirk only slept with women during their respective television series - which is obviously false, but bear with me - then Kirk has 11:79 as compared to Riker's 14:178, or 7:89. So Kirk wins that battle.

All of this isn't counting books, where who knows how many women, men, transgendered species, farm animals and household objects these two - especially Riker, whose standards are never shown to be all that high - have slept with in them.